# Linq multiple table grouping

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, grouping

I can't seem to get the grouping right with these tables to get the result I need. I have the following linq expression, which is only giving me the last item under "Software Title":

```
List<Inventory> inventoryList = (from u in users
                                 join s in db.software on u.userId equals s.ownerId
                                 select new Inventory { UserId = u.userId, FirstName = u.firstName, LastName = u.lastName, SoftwareTitle = s.title }).ToList();

var currentInventory = inventoryList.GroupBy(i => i.UserId)
                                    .Select(grp => grp.First()).ToList();
```

This is what I get for results:

First Name       Last Name          Software Title
James              Smith                  Photoshop
Mike                 Jones                 Microft Office
Tim                   Williams             Microsoft Office

I need results like this though:

First Name       Last Name          Software Title
James              Smith                  Illustrator, Microsoft Office, Photoshop
Mike                 Jones                 Visual Studio, Microft Office 
Tim                   Williams             Photoshop, Microsoft Office

I can't figure out how to do a join on "s.title", so that it will give me a comma separated list. When I tried string.join(",", s.title.ToArray()),I just got an array of characters like P,h,o,t,o,s,h,o,p for example.

Comment: Can you add the setup of the collections to the question?

Comment: The data is coming from the database. I'm using Entity Framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want something like

```
var currentInventory = (from u in users
                        join s in db.software on u.UserId equals s.OwnerId
                        group s.title by u into grp
                        select grp)
                        .AsEnumerable()
                        .Select(grp => new Inventory 
                        { 
                            UserId = grp.Key.userId, 
                            FirstName = grp.Key.firstName, 
                            LastName = grp.Key.lastName, 
                            SoftwareTitle = string.Join(", ", grp) 
                        })
                        .ToList();
```

But this depends on the items in `users` being setup correctly for grouping, which I'm assuming they are since you seem to be joining them with a EF table.  That's also why I put the `AsEnumerable` in there because `string.Join` isn't going to work in an EF query.

Comment: Awesome! That is exactly what I was after. Thank very much.